# Stripe checkout: Pass metadata on Session object creation and receive it in checkout.session.completed event

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I'm implementing Stripe checkout on a website and I want to pass some specific data on checkout.session.complete.
Here is what I tried:

```
'mode' => 'payment',
'payment_intent_data' => [
    'metadata' => [
        'eventId' => $eventId,
    ],
 ],
```

But I don't receive those datas in my webhook. What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`payment_intent_data` gets added to the resulting `PaymentIntent` object, not the `Checkout\Session` object. It won't be present in the `checkout.session.complete` webhook data you're sent.

(The `PaymentIntent`'s ID will be, so if you like, you could request that object's data as part of your webhook processing. You could also collect the `payment_intent.created` webhook type, but you'd have to correlate it after the fact with the session.)

The easier approach here is probably setting a `client_reference_id` on the Checkout Session. This ID **is** passed back via the webhook, and can be any arbitrary string you like - it could be a session or cache key that let you look up the metadata you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your help ! I will try to find the PaymentIntent id because I'm already using client_reference_id to send the userId

Comment: @ThomasCoumes Sounds good. I haven't run into a character limit on `client_reference_id` yet - you might consider trying to put JSON in there as an even simpler potential approach.

Comment: that's clever ! I will probably do that, thank you !